# How to mock method from other class in a loop using PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I hava a public void method "a" which is to be tested, and in "a" I have a loop with string as iterator , in this loop I called B's public void method with the string iterator as parameter which I want to mock, I want to write a unit test to test "a" using PowerMock, how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Do you have any static methods refernces in method "a",  if not use Mockito directly, PowerMock is bascially used to stub static methods, mock private variables, constructors etc..and I hope you aren't doing integration testing so just mock class B's method  and use Mockito.doverify method to check whether your method is actually called or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any static methods refernces in method "a", if not use Mockito directly, PowerMock is bascially used to stub static methods, mock private variables, constructors etc..and I hope you aren't doing integration testing so just mock class B's method and use Mockito.verify method to check whether your method is actually called or not. See my answer below.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class ClassATest {

@InjectMocks
ClassA classsA;
@Mock
ClassB classB;
@Test
public void testClassAMethod() {
    //Assuming ClassA has one method which takes String array,
    String[] inputStrings = {"A", "B", "C"}; 
    //when you call classAMethod, it intern calls getClassMethod(String input)
    classA.classAMethod(inputStrings); 
    //times(0) tells you method getClassBmethod(anyString()) been called zero times, in my example inputStrings length is three,
    //it will be called thrice
   //Mockito.verify(classB, times(0)).getClassBMethod(anyString());
    Mockito.verify(classB, times(3)).getClassBMethod(anyString());
    }
}
```